# .addEventListener - long list

Tags: javascript

I found few answer on my issue but probably I'm not so experienced to processes it to my case.

I have list of items generated to .html

```
<div id="grid">
```

by JavaScript

```
var div_block = "";
  for (i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
     div_block = div_block + '<div id="c' + i + '" class="card"></div>';
  }
document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = div_block;

for (i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
  'var c' + i + ' = document.getElementById(c' + i + ');'
}
```

and it works fine. 
I want to chose .addEventListner method to chose proper element but for 70 and more elements code:

```
c0.addEventListener("click", function () {revealCard(0);});
c1.addEventListener("click", function () {revealCard(1);});
...
cn.addEventListener("click", function () {revealCard(n);});
```

is huge and not elegant. Method I've tried didn't work

```
for (i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
  'c'+i+'.addEventListener("click", function() { revealCard('+i+'); });'
}
```

How to build working addEventListener() for this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you building strings? `'var c' + i + ' = document.getElementById(c' + i + ');'`

Comment: `'var c' + i + ' = document.getElementById(c' + i + ');'` and `'c'+i+'.addEventListener("click", function() { revealCard('+i+'); });'` is just generating strings containing JavaScript code. The code is not actually evaluated.

Comment: because I was not sure it will work without catching element (c0, c1,....) from HTML. I just delete it and it works. It means .addEventListner() can catch HTML id without document.getElementById() method? Still I don't know how to shorten addEventListner. Next step I want to use jQuery with $(element).on('click', function() { });, but step by step :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing can be solved by using the `card` class that you add on each of your card. Then, to refer to the right card, you can use the keyword `this`, which in the context of an `addEventListener` will refer to whichever DOM element received the click. You also won't need to generate a unique Id for each one of your div, which I think is a big plus.

Your code would look like this:

```
let div_block = "";

for (i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
  div_block = div_block + '<div class="card"></div>';
}

const cards = querySelectorAll(".card");

cards.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener("click", revealCard)
})

function revealCard(){
  // Here, `this` refers to the card that was clicked
  // So you can do what you want with it
  console.log(this);
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) are not supported natively by all browsers

Comment: @JuanCastillo Indeed. For reference, we can refer to this link to know which browser supports arrow function natively: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions.

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification to brk's answer, using a single event listener on the parent that will trigger for the events on the children

```js
var div_block = "";

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  div_block += `<div data-attr="${i}" id="c${i}" class="card">Hello</div>`;
}

var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
grid.innerHTML = div_block;

grid.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.getAttribute('class') === 'card') {
    revealCard(e.target.dataset.attr);
  }
});

function revealCard(num) {
  console.log(num)
}
```

```html
<div id='grid'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataset`, that is while creating the dom add a [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property.
Then use `querySelectorAll` to get all the div with class `card` and iterate over it to add event using `addEventListener`. On click of the element get the `dataset` value and pass to `revealCard` function

```js
var div_block = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  div_block += `<div data-attr="${i}" id="c${i}" class="card">Hello</div>`;
}
document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = div_block;
document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    revealCard(item.dataset.attr)
  })
})


function revealCard(num) {
  console.log(num)
}
```

```html
<div id='grid'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but I wouldn't use IDs and I wouldn't bind X event listeners. I would use event delegation and `data-*` attributes:

Build your list of elements:

```
const grid = document.getElementById("grid");
for (var i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
  const child = document.createElement('div');
  child.className = 'card';
  child.dataset.index = i;
  grid.appendChild(child);
}
```

Add an event listener to the grid element:

```
grid.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   let target = event.target;
   // traverse up if clicked inside element
   while (target.className !== 'card') {
     target = target.parentNode;
   }
   if (target) {
     revealCard(target.dataset.index);
   }
});
```

```js
const grid = document.getElementById("grid");
for (var i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
  const child = document.createElement('div');
  child.className = 'card';
  child.dataset.index = i;
  child.innerText = `Card ${i}`;
  grid.appendChild(child);
}



grid.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   let target = event.target;
   // traverse up if clicked inside element
   while (target.className !== 'card') {
     target = target.parentNode;
   }
   if (target) {
     revealCard(target.dataset.index);
   }
});

function revealCard(i) {
  console.log(`Card ${i} revealed`);
}
```

```html
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: thx Felix. Your suggestion is next level for me, I'll try it. By the way I returned a week ago from Trento resort (worked as a ski instructor in Serrada) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found probably the easiest (shortest) solution:

```
for(var i=0;i<boardSize;i++){
   document.getElementById('c'+i).addEventListener("click",function(){
   revealCard(this.id.substring(1));
   });
}
```

What do you thing?